# Scraping Text through sections using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So i am currently using scrapy to scrape a website. The website has n number sublinks which i was able to enter. Each sublink has 3 things i need title, description and content. I am able to get title, description but the content is split across n number of section where number of section differ per sublink like in this example
[image]

now i tried using loops to go through each section and store it but the yield functions gives me title,desc, and the content from the last section

below is code

```
def parse_instructions(self, response):
    title = response.xpath('//\*\[@id="d-article"\]/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/h1/text()').get()
    description = response.xpath('//\*\[@id="ency\_summary"\]/p/text()').getall()
    joined_description = ' '.join(description)
    sections = response.css('section div.section:not([class*=" "])')

    for section in sections:
        section_text = ' '.join(section.css('p::text').getall())
        section_text = ' '.join('a::text').getall()
        section_text = ' '.join('ul::text').getall()

    yield {
        "title": title,
        "description": joined_description,
        "section_text": section_text,
    }
```